# Get token from Openiddict by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, openiddict

I can get tokens from my Openiddict Server like this:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:7000/connect/token");
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "password",
                ["username"] = email,
                ["password"] = password
            });
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
            var tempt1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But When I call by jQuery and postman, I'm getting error:

```
    var body = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: email,
        password: password
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:7000/connect/token',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:  'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        header: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        data: body,
        complete: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result + " OK!");
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert(result + " CHYBA");
        },
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong. Please let me know. thanks

Comment: what is the error you're getting? Is there anything in dev-tools console?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta Bad request 400

Comment: that means the data being sent is not expected one. I would suggest to compare. Try your working solution and see the outgoing data in browser and compare that to the JQuery solution.

Comment: I using c# to call API get token and It's work, but I dont know what I'm doing wrong with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is wrong, you aren't sending JSON so remove `contentType:  'application/json; charset=UTF-8',`.
Also, Access-Control headers are sent from the server to the client, not the other way around.